# Unable to remove carriage returns in a LONG data type column using REPLACE function

Tags: sql, oracle, carriage-return

I am working on a `LONG` column in Oracle SQL Developer and this  column contains carriage returns that need to be removed. The error I'm getting after using :

`REPLACE ( col_name , CHR(13) , '' )` is :

> ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got LONG
>   00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"

Is there a workaround for this ?

Answers or suggestions will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to do almost anything with LONG data type columns. You should convert them to CLOB. You just found a reason why that is.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28393/adlob_long_lob.htm

There is a `to_lob()` function to convert LONG to CLOB, but that can only be used in the `select` portion of an `insert` statement (that is, it can only be used to convert a LONG column to a CLOB column). After the conversion, you should have no problems using text functions on the resulting CLOB. You may also want to look at CLOB-specific functions in the DBMS_LOB package:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_lob.htm#ARPLS600

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I was able to convert it to CLOB using an insert statement and then used TO_LOB function afterwards.

Comment: Cool! Now the real question: Do you have to work with LONG values often, or was this a very rare event? If you have to work with them often, you may want to convert to CLOB (as Oracle has been urging us all for the past 20 years), or influence those with the power to make this decision. Finding work-arounds for working with LONG wastes more time, resources, and money than the process of converting away from LONG once and for all. Good luck either way!